# How to unmarshal a protobuf record with const(golang) values changed

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am just started learning `protobuf` and `golang` for an existing project and am already stumped with a problem.

We have an existing `const` in `golang` from 0 to 5 and a map to string

```
const (
    A int32 = iota
    B
    C
    D
    E
    F
)

var IntToNames = map[int32]string{
    A:      "John",
    B:      "Doe",
    C:      "Foo",
    D:      "Bar",
    E:      "Jane",
    F:      "Doe",
}
```

The records are marshalled in stored in a DB with following `proto` file:

```
message nameRecord {
  bool topLevel = 1;
  map<string, int32> entries = 2;
}
```

The `int32` in that map corresponds to the `const` values 0-5

But now the requirement has popped up to have a different `const X` replace `C`.

```
const (
    A int32 = iota
    B
    X
    C
    D
    E
    F
)
```

As it is evident, values from C to F are now +1. When unmarshalling the already stored values from DB and mapping them back to names, those will be mapped to the wrong names

One solution would be to delete the DB altogether while upgrading and let it be rebuilt.

Or, maybe I could add an `int32 version` in `proto`. Newer entries would set this `version` and older ones would be missing this field.
Then in unmarshal(not sure if this works), check if the version is set and then adjust +1 for C-F.

But it all looks like a kludge :(

Is there would be some elegant way to handle this.

Comment: The obvious way to do this is to not do it, keep using your current list and adding X at the end for the database records, and then use the disordered list with X after B and before C for whatever purpose that is needed for. Other than that you are probably out of luck.

Comment: The `int` values define the weights of the `const` A newly introduce lower weightage const can't be placed at the end :( . I didn't understand your comment about `disordered list`, can u please elaborate on that ?

Comment: I mean somehow you untangle that so that you have different orderings for the database and for the other thing that you need the enumeration for. Other than that, surely you need to go back and untangle all of the entries in the database? There is no elegant solution here.